# How to alert with jQuery when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to alert something if a `<a>` is clicked, but only if there is a real link. I have this code but it doesn't really work...

```
$("a").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("href") != "#" && $(this).attr("href") != "") {
        alert("foo");
    }
});
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How is it not working? [This pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYBomK) shows this to be operating as requested.

Comment: How do you define a "*real*" link?

Comment: have you wrapped it inside `$(document).ready(function() {  ...... })`?

Comment: @Jdsfighter thanks for this pen - I forgot the event.preventDefault, now everything is working fine. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Aside from needing more info that "it doesn't really work", it sounds as if you're trying to do some very bad UI. Do you really really need to interrupt every single link on the page with an annoying popup? If the end goal is not actually to alert something but to do something else unobtrusive, fine, but otherwise I'd suggest a rethink.

Comment: @DougMcLean I am NOT doing a bad UI, more like a very good, because when clicked the loading icon appears.

Comment: Ah OK the `alert` wasn't the endgame. Phew! ;)

Comment: @Jdsfighter could you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling `e.preventDefault()` in the method.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    if ($(this).attr("href") != "#" && $(this).attr("href") != "") {
        alert("foo");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```